# Mini cart with zero price for all the configurable products except first item

Tags: magento2, cart, mini-cart

While adding set of configurable products to cart, it gets added and showing correct data in checkout/cart page, whereas in mini cart it is showing zero price for all the configurable products except the first item.

Please check the attachment for your reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution to the above-mentioned issue. While adding multiple items to the cart save() function should be outside the loop.

```
/* keep this outside the loop */ 
 $this->cart->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You Just need to update your add to cart action into your controller file.

Move your below code

```
$cart->save();
```

After completed your Foreach loop.

It's working for me.